# Is the black part of foods that got burning - called 'coal'?

Tags: word-request

Is the black part of foods that got burning - called 'coal'?

When putting a steak on a grill, sometimes it gets burn and we see black scorched place where the fire touched it (See the attached photo below, that visualizes what I'm saying). What is this black matter called? The same can be with a piece of bread in a toaster. Can I call it coal?

Based on [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coal) it seems that this name is for "a hard, black substance that is **dug from the earth** in pieces, and can be burned to produce heat or power, or a single piece of this". So, it seems that I can't use it, then if it is true, what's the name for this thing?

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coal

Comment: Very related: [What do you call or how do you describe this in English? overcooking the food? What do you call the black stuff?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/167709/41273)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Coal is compressed carbon, often used as an energy source.

The portions of food(especially meat) that is blackened through cooking is referred to as "char". However, in my experience, it is more common to use the adjective form "charred", as in "the meat is charred" or the "charred portion of the chicken".

Comment: You can also call it "blackened". If you are unhappy or it is now inedible, you can say it is "burnt".